# Is there a way to integrate Google Hangouts with Canvas LMS?

Tags: integration, google-hangouts, lti, canvas-lms

Specifically, from one of Instructure Canvas’ groups pages, like Conference or Pages or Discussions, I want to be able to authenticate with, and connect to Google Hangouts (using custom Javascript code), resulting in a new Google Hangouts video window.

1. The envisioned workflow is this:
       1.1. Student logs into Canvas LMS with her Canvas ID.

   1.2. Student joins one of her existing groups.

   1.3. Student goes to a module such as “Conferences” or “Pages” or “Discussions”.

   1.4. Student sees a Javascript-driven button that says “Join a Hangout”.

   1.5. This kicks off a Google OAuth2 authentication workflow.

   1.6. Student uses her personal Google ID to authenticate with Google.

   1.7. After successful authentication, student is taken to the custom URL where the custom Google Hangouts video conference is running.
2. Would I need to setup OAuth2 authentication/integration with Canvas LMS? Or is that already included as a part of Canvas? I understand that there *might* already be such an setup done to support integration with Google Drive. In a group’s “Collaborations” module, I already see a "Google Docs” integration. If that’s the case, would I need to re-implement a Google OAuth2 connection for integrating with Google Hangouts, or can I reuse what’s already there?
3. I'm working on a custom Google Hangouts app, and I’ve integrated Moodle with my custom Google hangouts through a button using specific Javascript code that’s available here: https://github.com/getsmarter/moodle-rhythm_hangout/blob/master/module.js. I’d need to use similar code in canvas to try to launch/join a Google Hangout. Would it be possible to incorporate such functionality (effectively a “Join a Hangout”) button into a Canvas group’s Conferences/ Pages/ Discussions module?
4. My users (students) would use their own personal Google IDs to log into, authenticate into and use my custom Google Hangouts app. I suspect the the same thing applies to the Collaborations module with Google Docs - users can use their personal Google IDs. Is there any place where Canvas stores the mapping/ connection between users’ Google IDs and their Canvas login IDs?
5. My custom Google Hangouts app needs a “mapping” or connection between the Google ID, the canvas ID, the student’s course (ID) and the student’s group (ID). I assume this doesn’t exist in Canvas and would need custom development? Or is there a way to store this information into Google Sheets, for example, from within Canvas?
6. Is LTI the only way to do this? Or is there another way?